# Is the operator norm of the canonical surjection $X\to X/U$ equal to $1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, quotient-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed space, $U$ be a closed subspace of $X$ and $\pi:X\to X/U$ denote the canonical projection. By definition, $\pi$ is surjective and it is easy to show that $\pi\left(B^X_1(0)\right)=B^{X/U}_1(0)$, where $B^X_1(0)$ and $B^{X/U}_1(0)$ denote the open unit balls around $0$ in $X$ and $X/U$, respectively.

It should immediately follow that $\pi$ is an open map and the operator norm of $\pi$ is at most $1$. But can we show that the operator norm is precisely equal to $1$ (unless $X=U$, of course)?

Comment: What you say is true in finite dimensional spaces. Indeed, let $U'$ be a complement of $U$ (i.e. $X = U \oplus U'$), then there is a canonical isomorphism $U' \cong X/U$. For all $x \in U'$ you have $\pi(x)=x$. I think that this argument can be generalized for any normed space, however I'm not sure about existence of complements.

Comment: @Crostul the existence of complements as a vector space exist regardless of dimension; the problem is that they may not be closed subspaces (e.g. there exist dense hyperplanes)

Comment: @0xbadf00d How did you show $\pi(B_1^X(0))=B_1^{X/U}(0)$? I see the $\subseteq$, but not the other inclusion.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Let $x\in X$ with $\varepsilon:=1-\left\|x+U\right\|>0$. Then there is a $x_0\in U$ with $\left\|x-x_0\right\|<\left\|x+U\right\|+\varepsilon=1$ and hence $\pi(x)=\pi(x-x_0)\in\pi(B^X_1(0))$.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Thanks, I very much confused myself :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is also immediate from $\pi(B_1^X(0))=B_1^{X/U}(0)$. If the norm of $\pi$ were strictly less than $1$, we would have $\pi(B_1^X(0))\subseteq \|\pi\|B_1^{X/U}(0)\subsetneq B_1^{X/U}(0)$.

Comment: Indeed, that is quite direct :)

Comment: I think you need to exclude the case $U=X$ explicitly, since in that case it should hold $$\underbrace{\|\pi\|}_{=0}B_1^{X/U}(0)=B_1^{X/U}(0)=\{0+X\}$$ or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You need that there exists a non-zero vector in $X/U$ to have a proper inclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Fix $\varepsilon \in (0,1)$. If $S$ is proper (and closed) by Riesz's lemma applied to $1-\varepsilon$ there exists $v \in X$ such that $\|v\| = 1$ and $\|\pi(v)\| = d(v,S) \geq 1-\varepsilon$. Hence $\|\pi\| \geq 1-\varepsilon$; now let $\varepsilon \to 0$.

Comment: We have $$\vert \pi_1(1,0)\vert = \vert 1\vert = 1 = \Vert (1,0)\Vert_2.$$ So, the operator norm is equal to $1$.

Comment: Sorry, I've clearly intended to exclude the trivial case $U=X$.

Comment: I've updated my answer, now with a proof for the non-trivial case. I'd appreciate a sanity check, nonetheless.

Comment: @guidoar Very nice answer! Did not see your edit while typing. Hope you don't mind if I keep my answer.

Comment: The more approaches available the better :)

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Would you please add more explanation to the proof in your comment on Feb 1, 2021, at 10:41 or, at least, explain the notation.

Comment: @user0 I'm afraid I can't. I guess this was a reply to a (now) deleted comment.

Answer (score 1):

If $U\neq X$, then your projection has norm equal to $1$. Assume it doesn't and let $c=\Vert \pi\Vert<1$, then we have for every $x\in X$
$$ \Vert \pi x\Vert \leq c\Vert x\Vert.$$
This means there exists $u_1\in U$ such that
$$ \Vert x + u_1\Vert \leq (1+c)/2 \Vert x \Vert.$$
Now we apply the same argument to $x+u_1$ and find $u_2\in U$ such that
$$ \Vert x +u_2\Vert \leq [(1+c)/2]^2 \Vert x\Vert.$$
Thus, by induction we find a sequence $(u_n)_{n\geq 1}\subseteq U$ that converges to $x$. As $x$ as arbitrary, we get that $U$ is dense and as $U$ is closed, we get $U=X$.